# Select the minimum of two dates

Tags: oracle

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT min( date_1, date_2)
from dual;
```

But this will fail terribly because min only takes one parameter. Is there another way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(date_1, date_2) FROM DUAL;
```

Oracle [LEAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm)

Comment: Is there a 'LEAST' equivalent in SSMS?

Comment: SSMS2012: _'LEAST' is not a recognized built-in function name._

Comment: opposite  is greatest

Comment: `null` is returned if either date is null, and same goes for the opposite `GREATEST` function.

Comment: @jeffrey I tried the following code :
select least('26-APR-2018','22-MAY-2018') from dual; but this always return '22-MAY-2018' as answer.

Comment: @Nidheesh, those are string literals, not dates.

Answer (score 13):

Try using `CASE` instead of `MIN` to compare the two and return the smaller value:

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN date_1<date_2 THEN date_1 ELSE date_2 END FROM dual;
```

Source: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Comment: You might also want to add a coalesce to those comparison unless your date columns do not allow nulls.